# download pdf directly without the save confirmation. Automate in node js

Tags: node.js, download

I am looking for a node JS code for downloading the pdf directly without the Save confirmation popup.
On clicking DOWNLOAD the system should directly save the pdf without another popup to Save/Ok

Comment: I think you are talking about a browser behavior, not something you can change server side. Or do you want it to just download for display purposes as opposed to having it downloaded as a saved file?

Comment: I am automating a LogIn in NodeJS which after a successful login, on clicking a 'Download Report' should download the pdf directly to the computer. On manually testing it does so. However when i run my script after clicking the 'Download Report' it would give a javascript popup for confirmation to save.

Comment: I had handled this in Selenium using profile setting:(shown below). I am unable to do so in NodeJS. Selenium Code was:

Comment: FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
  // MIME type for zip file "aaplication/pdf"
  // setting for automatic download of the Neilsens Pdf report.
  profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",false);
  profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","application/pdf");
  profile.setPreference("plugin.disable_full_page_plugin_for_types","application/pdf");
  profile.setPreference("pdfjs.disabled", true);
  // 0 = desktop, 1 = default download folder , 2 = user defined location.